# Prove Validity of verbal argument in discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

"It is not the case that if electric rates go up, then usage will go down, nor is it true that either new power plants will be built or bills will not be late. Therefore usage will not go down and bills will be late."

Is it valid argument? then how?

Comment: Hint: $A \implies B \iff [(\neg A) \vee B].$  Therefore $\neg [A \implies B] \iff [A \wedge (\neg B)].$

Comment: "It is not the case that it seems you have worked on your homework. Therefore, work first, then we will help you" is a valid argument

Comment: @JeanMarie
is my answer correct?

Comment: This depends on whether you are using proposition or predicate logic.  Propositional logic your answer seems to be correct.  But in english it is obviously invalid (you tell us what you can't conclude but nothing about what you *can* conclude).  Natural language is more predicate than proposition. "Rates will go up" is not a true/false proposition. It's a conditional statement whose truth may have many factors. Rather than $A=$'rates will go up' its more accurate to say $A(x)=$'rates will go up in event $x$'.

Answer (score 2):

Let, electric rate goes up = A; usage going down = B; new power plant will be built = C; bills will not be late = D

The verbal argument can be now expressed in the following way:
( A → B )’ ∧ ( C ∨ D)’ → B’ ∧ D’

Now,

1. ( A → B )’      Hypotheses
2. ( C ∨ D)’       Hypotheses
3. (A’ ∨ B)’       1, Simplification
4. A ∧ B’          3, De Morgan’s’
5. B’          4, Simplification
6. C ‘ ∧ D’            2, De Morgan’s
7. D’          6, Simplification
8. B’ ∧ D’         5,7, Conjunction

Therefore, the verbal argument is valid!